# ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread SparkListenerBus

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I try to execute simple project with Apache Spark. This is my code SimpleApp.scala

```
/* SimpleApp.scala */
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object SimpleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val logFile = "/home/hduser/spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4/README.md" // Should be some file on your system
    // val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
    val sc = new SparkContext("local", "Simple Job", "/home/hduser/spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4/")
    val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
    val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("hadoop")).count()
    val numBs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("see")).count()
    println("Lines with hadoop: %s, Lines with see: %s".format(numAs, numBs))
  }
}
```

when I manually send this job to Spark with command line : `/home/hduser/spark-1.2.0-hadoop-2.4.0/bin/spark-submit --class "SimpleApp" --master local[4] target/scala-2.10/simple-project_2.10-1.0.jar` it's run successfully.

if I run with `sbt run` and with the service apache spark is running, it's success, but in the end of log it give error like this :

```
15/02/06 15:56:49 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread SparkListenerBus
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:996)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1303)
    at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.acquire(Semaphore.java:317)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(LiveListenerBus.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1460)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1.run(LiveListenerBus.scala:46)
15/02/06 15:56:49 ERROR ContextCleaner: Error in cleaning thread
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning$1.apply$mcV$sp(ContextCleaner.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning$1.apply(ContextCleaner.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning$1.apply(ContextCleaner.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1460)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner.org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning(ContextCleaner.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anon$3.run(ContextCleaner.scala:65)
```

Any wrong in my code? Thanks in advance.
I use apache spark 1.2.0-bin-hadoop-2.4, scala 2.10.4

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According [this mail archive](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-spark-user/201406.mbox/%3CCAMJOb8=6Q9xDhLALyo-bWQR3AkMz=ost=7jhTad7Zduv7mpQ0w@mail.gmail.com%3E), i.e.:

> Hi Haoming,
>
> You can safely disregard this error. This is printed at the end of the
>   execution when we clean up and kill the daemon context cleaning
>   thread. In the future it would be good to silence this particular
>   message, as it may be confusing to users.
>
> Andrew

the error could be disregarded.

Comment: ohh i see sir. i think the problem come from my code, but in fact it's log for cleaning the job of spark. thankyou sir.

Comment: Is this issue resolved? I'm running hive-on-spark with spark-1.5.1 and hive-1.2.1 in yarn-cluster mode. Receiving the same error "uncaught error in thread SparkListenerBus, stopping SparkContext
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
"

Comment: @Arvindkumar that issue is resolved and now, i can use it normally.

Answer (score 49):

The `SparkContext` or `SparkSession` (Spark >= 2.0.0) should be stopped when the Spark code is run by adding `sc.stop` or `spark.stop` (Spark >= 2.0.0) at the end of the code.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about this.

Comment: I guess this should be the answer.