# Cannot load main class from JAR file

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, sbt

I have a Spark-scala application. I tried to display a simple message -  "Hello my App". When I compile it with `sbt compile` and run it by `sbt run` it's fine.  I displayed my message with success but he display an error; like this:

```
Hello my application!
16/11/27 15:17:11 ERROR Utils: uncaught error in thread SparkListenerBus,   stopping SparkContext
        java.lang.InterruptedException
     ERROR ContextCleaner: Error in cleaning thread
    java.lang.InterruptedException
     at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anon$1.run(ContextCleaner.scala:67)
    16/11/27 15:17:11 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.0.2.15:4040
    [success] Total time: 13 s, completed Nov 27, 2016 3:17:12 PM
    16/11/27 15:17:12 INFO DiskBlockManager: Shutdown hook called
```

I can't understand whether it's fine or not!
Also when I try to load my file jar after the run, it displays an error.

My command line look like:

```
spark-submit "appfilms" --master local[4] target/scala-2.11/system-of-recommandation_2.11-1.0.jar
```

And the error is:

```
Error: Cannot load main class from JAR file:/root/projectFilms/appfilms
Run with --help for usage help or --verbose for debug output
16/11/27 15:24:11 INFO Utils: Shutdown hook called
```

Please can you answer me!

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error message said? use --help or --verbose on the spark submit to see what the logs have to say.

Comment: AFAIK it should be submitted with `--jars` option like ...  `$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit 
--driver-class-path  your jar[s] 
--jars your jar[s] `

Comment: can you try this `spark-submit \

--verbose --master local[4] \

--class yourclass yourjar.jar`

Comment: if neither is working `jar -tvf system-of-recommandation_2.11-1.0.jar | grep appfilms ` to check the expected class is there in jar file

Comment: also check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796818/how-to-append-a-resource-jar-for-spark-submit?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that the SparkContext is not stopped, this is required in versions higher than Spark 2.x.
This should be stopped to prevent this error by `SparkContext.stop()`, or `sc.stop()`. Inspiration for solving this error is gained from own experiences and the following sources: [Spark Context](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html), [Spark Listener Bus error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28362341/error-utils-uncaught-exception-in-thread-sparklistenerbus)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to use --class Parameter
spark-submit "appfilms" --master local[4] target/scala-2.11/system-of-recommandation_2.11-1.0.jar

spark-submit --class "appfilms" --master local[4] target/scala-2.11/system-of-recommandation_2.11-1.0.jar.

Please note if appfilm belong to any package dont forgot to add package name as below
packagename.appfilms

I believe this will suffice

Comment: I forget the add the `--class` which is probably the same as what you suggested.